# ¿Cómo actualizar un formulario de "editar" con jquery en un modal usando ajax para validar?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel-8

verán intento actualizar un cliente usando ajax y jquery, este cliente tiene un RFC único por lo cual quiero validar que al intentar editar el RFC no pongan uno ya existente. Para esto lo que hice fue poner dos inputs, uno trae el RFC y el otro me trae el id del cliente, al momento de intentar editar el RFC se activa el evento de jquery **keyup** con el cual envio lo que contiene el input por ajax, con una consulta busco las coincidencias: **si el id = id y el RFC = RFC** es decir que se dio cliq en el input pero no se modifico ninguna letra,  entonces que me devuelva un mensaje diciendo que el RFC que se intenta editar pertenece al propio registro, en cambio si **id != id y RFC = RFC** es decir si el rfc existe pero el id no es igual entonces envia un mensaje diciendo que el rfc ya pertenece a otro registro, por ultimo si **id != id y RFC != RFC** envie un mensaje "RFC disponible":

> Controlador

```
    public function ajaxRequestPostRFCEditar(Request $request)
    {

    $jsonData = array();

    $RFC = $request->rfc;
    $idRFC = $request->idRFCEditarE;

    // Da 1 si encuentra coincidencia
    // Da 0 si no encuentra coincidencias

    $buscarRFC =  cliente::select('id','RFC','razonSocial') 
    ->where([
        ['id', '=', $idRFC], 
        ['RFC','=', $RFC] 
    ])
    ->get();

    $buscarRFC2 = cliente::select('RFC','razonSocial')
            ->where('RFC','=', $RFC)
            ->get();
 

    $existeRFC = count($buscarRFC);

      $existeRFC2 = count($buscarRFC2);

    if($existeRFC > 0 && $existeRFC2 > 0){

            $jsonData['success'] = 0;

          $jsonData['message'] = '<p style="color: black;"><strong style="color: green;">RFC ('.$RFC.')</strong></p>';

        }else if($existeRFC <= 0 && $existeRFC2 > 0){

             $jsonData['success'] = 1;

           $jsonData['message'] = '<p style="color: black;"><strong style="color: red;">El RFC ('.$RFC.') ya existe para otro registro</strong> </p>';

        }else if($existeRFC <= 0 && $existeRFC2 <= 0){

            $jsonData['success'] = 2;

           $jsonData['message'] = '<p style="color: black;"><strong style="color: green;">RFC ('.$RFC.') disponible</strong></p>';

        }

        return response()->json(
            [
                'success' =>  $jsonData['success'],
                'message' =>  $jsonData['message']
            ]
        );


}
```

El problema surge porque para todos los clientes me toma el mismo id, al darle clic inspeccionar si me aparece el id que corresponde al registro que estoy editando pero al enviarlo por ajax me toma siempre el id del primer registro de mi tabla (estoy utilizando modals para editar)

> Formulario

```
 <!-- COMIENZA MODAL EDITAR CLIENTE -->
<form action="{{ route('admin.clientes.update', $c->id) }}" method="POST">
    @csrf @method('PUT')
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade modalEditar" name="myModalE" id="myModalE{{ $c->id }}" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h4 class="modal-title">{{ __('Editar cliente') }}</h4>  
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
 
    <div class="form-row" id="grupo__rfcEditar">
            <div class="form-group col-4 formulario__grupo">
                  <input class="id" type="text" id="idClienteEditar" name="idClienteEditar" value="{{ $c->id }}" hidden>
                   <strong>{{ __('RFC') }}:</strong>
                    <input class="form-control formulario__input" type="text" name="rfcEditar" id="rfcEditar" value="{{ $c->RFC }}" maxlength="14" minlength="10">
                    <div id="respuestaRFCEditar"></div>
            </div>

                    <div class="form-group col-6 formulario__grupo">
                            <strong>{{ __('Razón social') }}:</strong>
                            <input class="form-control formulario__input" type="text" name="razonSocialEditar" id="razonSocialEditar" value="{{ $c->razonSocial }}">
                    </div>
    </div>
<div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" data-dismiss="modal" onclick="cerrarModal();">Regresar</button>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="btn-successEditar">Guardar cambios</button>
      </div>
```

> jquery

```js
$(document).on('keyup', '.formulario__input', function(e) {

  const target = $(e.currentTarget);
  var rfc = target.val();

  var longitudRFC = target.val().length;

  var idRFCEditar = $('.modalEditar #idClienteEditar').val();

  // console.log(rfc);
  //console.log(idRFCEditar);

  if (longitudRFC === 0) {


    $('.modalEditar #razonSocialEditar').attr('disabled', false);
    $('.modalEditar #calleEditar').attr('disabled', false); //
    $('.modalEditar #numeroEditar').attr('disabled', false); //
    $('.modalEditar #coloniaEditar').attr('disabled', false); //
    $('.modalEditar #codigoPostalEditar').attr('disabled', false); //
    $('.modalEditar #emailEditar').attr('disabled', false); //
    $('.modalEditar #telefonoEditar').attr('disabled', false);
  }

  if (longitudRFC < 10) {

    $(".modalEditar #respuestaRFCEditar").html("<strong style='color: red'>El rfc debe contener entre 10 y 14 caracteres</strong>");
    document.getElementById('grupo__rfcEditar').classList.add('formulario__grupo-incorrecto');

    $('.modalEditar #razonSocialEditar').attr('disabled', true);
    $('.modalEditar #calleEditar').attr('disabled', true); //
    $('.modalEditar #numeroEditar').attr('disabled', true); //
    $('.modalEditar #coloniaEditar').attr('disabled', true); //
    $('.modalEditar #codigoPostalEditar').attr('disabled', true); //
    $('.modalEditar #emailEditar').attr('disabled', true); //
    $('.modalEditar #telefonoEditar').attr('disabled', true);
    $('.modalEditar #btn-successEditar').attr('disabled', true);


  }

  //console.log(longitudRFC);
  else if (longitudRFC >= 10 || longitudRFC <= 14) {


    var a = 'rfc=' + rfc;
    var idRFCEditarE = $("#idClienteEditar", this).val();

    alert(idRFCEditarE);
    $.ajaxSetup({
      headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
      }
    });

    var url = '{{ url('
    validarRFCEditar ') }}';

    $.ajax({
      url: url,
      method: 'POST',
      data: {
        idRFCEditarE,
        rfc
      },
      dataType: "JSON",
      success: function(response) {
        if (response.success == 0) {

          alert('Entre a opcion 0 ya existe en el propio registro');

          $(".modalEditar #respuestaRFCEditar").html("");
          //  document.getElementById('grupo__rfcEditar').classList.remove('formulario__grupo-incorrecto');
          //   document.getElementById('grupo__rfcEditar').classList.add('formulario__grupo-correcto'); 
          //  $('#respuestaRFCEditar').html(response.message)
          $('.modalEditar #btn-successEditar').attr('disabled', false);
          $('.modalEditar #razonSocialEditar').attr('disabled', false);
          $('.modalEditar #calleEditar').attr('disabled', false); //
          $('.modalEditar #numeroEditar').attr('disabled', false); //
          $('.modalEditar #coloniaEditar').attr('disabled', false); //
          $('.modalEditar #codigoPostalEditar').attr('disabled', false); //
          $('.modalEditar #emailEditar').attr('disabled', false); //
          $('.modalEditar #telefonoEditar').attr('disabled', false);

        } else if (response.success == 1) {

          alert('Entre a opcion 1 no cumple condicion');
          $(".modalEditar #respuestaRFCEditar").html("");
          $('.modalEditar #respuestaRFCEditar').html(response.message);
          //  document.getElementById('grupo__rfcEditar').classList.remove('formulario__grupo-correcto'); 
          // document.getElementById('grupo__rfcEditar').classList.add('formulario__grupo-incorrecto');
          $('.modalEditar #razonSocialEditar').attr('disabled', true);
          $('.modalEditar #calleEditar').attr('disabled', true); //
          $('.modalEditar #numeroEditar').attr('disabled', true); //
          $('.modalEditar #coloniaEditar').attr('disabled', true); //
          $('.modalEditar #codigoPostalEditar').attr('disabled', true); //
          $('.modalEditar #emailEditar').attr('disabled', true); //
          $('.modalEditar #telefonoEditar').attr('disabled', true);
          $('.modalEditar #btn-successEditar').attr('disabled', true);
          $('.modalEditar #btn-successEditar').attr('disabled', true);

        } else if (response.success == 2) {

          alert('Entre a opcion 2 disponible para cambio');

          $(".modalEditar #respuestaRFCEditar").html("");
          // document.getElementById('grupo__rfcEditar').classList.remove('formulario__grupo-incorrecto');
          //  document.getElementById('grupo__rfcEditar').classList.add('formulario__grupo-correcto'); 
          $('.modalEditar #respuestaRFCEditar').html(response.message)
          $('.modalEditar #btn-successEditar').attr('disabled', false);

          $('.modalEditar #razonSocialEditar').attr('disabled', false);
          $('.modalEditar #calleEditar').attr('disabled', false); //
          $('.modalEditar #numeroEditar').attr('disabled', false); //
          $('.modalEditar #coloniaEditar').attr('disabled', false); //
          $('.modalEditar #codigoPostalEditar').attr('disabled', false); //
          $('.modalEditar #emailEditar').attr('disabled', false); //
          $('.modalEditar #telefonoEditar').attr('disabled', false);

        }

      },
      error: function(error) {
        console.log(error)
      }
    });


  }

});
```

> Video para que se vea mas claro que es lo que pasa al intentar editar, con un alert mando traer el valor id

https://zwdrive.com/8QMLf3

Como se puede ver en el video para todos los registros me toma el mismo id...al inspeccionar si me muestra el id del registro pero al correr el evento no

https://zwdrive.com/jDhBS7